# How $A^0=I$ in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

In number theory we know that $$a^0=1$$ if $a \ne 0$

This we can prove using properties of indices as: if $m$ and $n$ are any two Non zero Real numbers

$$\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n}$$

Putting $m=n$ we get $$a^0=\frac{a^m}{a^m}=1$$

But is this True in Matrices?

if i use same proof then i have to assume that $A$ is Invertible.

But is $$A^0=I$$ for any Non Null matrix whether it is Singular or Non Singular ?

Comment: Yes, we do have $A^0=I$.

Comment: is it true for Singular matrices? that is what my main query

Comment: It is true for _any_ matrix.

Comment: One point worth mentioning here is that there is no problem with defining $0^0=1$ as long as the exponents are limited to _integers_ (or natural numbers) (of course, $0$ raised to a negative power is still undefined). The analogous result goes for matrices. If you want exponents to be real and to fulfill reasonable continuity properties, then $0^0$ becomes problematic.

Comment: As far as I know, $a^0=1$ is typically a defining property of exponentiation (including in the linear algebra context). See for instance the discussion on the Wikipedia page for exponentiation in regards to generalizations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Generalizations.

Comment: Note that $a^ma^0=a^m\Rightarrow a^0=1$ (if you take $a^ma^n=a^{m+n}$ as an axiom.

Comment: Fractional powers are complicated for matrices.  Just as for real numbers, some matrices may have no square root but, unlike real numbers, others may have more than two square roots.  For example, any reflection is a square root of the identity.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel any matrix, or any square matrix?

Comment: @Bey Square matrices only.