# Why is $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right)^0\ne1$?

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, mathematica

Why is

$\left( \begin{array}{cc}  1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right)^0=\left( \begin{array}{cc}  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \end{array} \right)$

This result me returns Mathematica on this command

```
Limit[MatrixFunction[#^s &, ( { {1, 1}, {1, 1} } )], s -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

Result:

```
{{1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}
```

Should not anything rised to zeroth power be $1$?

Comment: How do you define $A^0$? I would say that $A^0 = 1$ for any non-zero matrix $A$, by definition.

Comment: @QuantumSpace as a limit with the power going to 0 from above.

Comment: So $A^0 = \lim_{t \searrow 0} A^t$? Then how do you define $A^t$ for $t > 0$?

Comment: @QuantumSpace a computer algebra system (Mathematica) helps.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296197/how-a0-i-in-matrices).

Comment: Well, $A$ is a singular matrix. The real exponential function need not be continuous at zero when the base is singular. It's the same old $0^0=1$ vs. $\lim_{s\to 0^+}0^s=0$ issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a limit it is like $0^0$. So you shouldn't write $A^0$. You can diagonalize it, it has eigenvalues 2,0 with corresponding eigenvectors,

$$E = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

So now we can look at the nth power as,

$$A^n = E^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 2^n & 0 \\ 0 & 0^n \end{bmatrix} E$$

Taking the limit of this as $n \to 0^+$ now we have $2^0=1$ in the upper entry and we end up with your result.

Comment: This only supports the result from the question. Here exponentiation is even continuous, but still the result is the same!

Comment: And shows that it is continuous and the limit from below is the same!

Comment: $0^0$ has no limit from below. Your expression has. As well, along the imaginary axis, and it is the same.

Comment: This is only valid for $n>0$. You can imagine there being a $0^n$ term there in the bottom right corner where I only wrote $0$ for the positive limit. Negative $n$ would be like dividing by zero.

Comment: Your last comment sheds some light indees. But from there the $0^n$ would occur there?

Comment: I don't understand your question, I guess to put it another way, this matrix simply doesn't have an inverse because of the column of 0s, it's linearly dependent, so a negative exponent power is just not possible.

Comment: Where this middle matrix comes from?

Comment: It comes from diagonalization, they're the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: Oops, I see, 0 is the second eigenvalue.

Comment: Let $J=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}\;$ then everyone (including Mathematica) agrees that the exponential map is  
$$\eqalign{
\exp(J) &= \pmatrix{4.19453&3.19453\\3.19453&4.19453} \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{J^k}{k!} \\
}$$
However, if you take $J^0=\tfrac 12J\ne I\,$ then you'll obtain the wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 &  1 \end{bmatrix}^0$$

could be any symmetric $2×2$ matrix with an eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ having eigenvector $1$, to wit:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & 1-a \\ 1-a &  a \end{bmatrix}$$

Any such matrix multiplied by right or left by $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 &  1 \end{bmatrix}$ gives back $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 &  1 \end{bmatrix}$ and thus qualifies potentially as a zero power by the multiplicative definition of exponentiation.

This unsatisfactory result stems from the fact that all rows and columns of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 &  1 \end{bmatrix}$ are multiples of a specific vector, or more generally that they are linearly dependent, or getting to the crux of the matter, the input matrix is singular!  Just as with numbers running the multiplicative recursion backwards fails to give $0^0=1$ because $0$ lacks a multiplicative inverse, so it is with matrices.

In the case of $0^0$ there are definitions of exponentiation (with limited domains on the exponent) that effectively force $0^0=1$, but matrices with their greater degree of freedom are harder to pin down and give less predictable results.  Something in the way Mathematica defines matrix exponentiation, or perhaps the limit process used in the program,, led it to a specific value of an intrinsically undefined zero-power of a singular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$A^0$ is the identity matrix. This then satisfies the rule
$$A^{m+n}=A^mA^n$$
which would not be true with your value for $A^0$.

Your question should be why is the limit not $I$?

Comment: Everything depends on the notation and the definition. By $1$ he might be referring to identity matrix. The question is vague.

Comment: @FreeMind I meant this: $\underset{s\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)^s$

Comment: @FreeMind And this result me returns Mathematica on this command Limit[MatrixFunction[#^s &, ( {
    {1, 1},
    {1, 1}
   } )], s -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]

Comment: Not only limit, see the answer by Merosity. It is continuous, and the limit from below is the same!